# Select Sphinx theme based on the builder

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx for generating documentation for a Windows project.  I generate two types of documentation: HTML and Microsoft Compiled HTML Help.  I'd like to generate these with different themes.

Here is a toy project which demonstrates the issue:

```
project\
   +-- source\
   |     +-- conf.py
   |     +-- contents.rst
   +-- make-doc.bat
```

source/conf.py:

```
project = 'Example'

html_theme = 'classic'
#html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

htmlhelp_basename = 'example'
```

source/contents.rst:

```
Contents
========

Content here
```

make-doc.bat:

```
SET SPHINX_BUILD="C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\sphinx-build.exe"
SET HHC="C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe"

RMDIR /S/Q build

%SPHINX_BUILD%  source build\html

%SPHINX_BUILD% -b htmlhelp source build\htmlhelp
%HHC% build\htmlhelp\example.hhp
```

Run `make-doc.bat`, and the HTML Help looks "ok", and the `example.chm` looks fine.

Change "conf.py" to use `'sphinx_rtd_theme'`, then run `make-doc.bat` again.  Now the HTML Help looks "great".  But when you open `example.chm`, a Javascript error is immediately displayed.  This error pops up for every page you navigate to (which is the only page in this toy project).

Clearly, there is an incompatibility between the `sphinx_rtd_theme` and Microsoft HTML Help Compiler.

Until that bug / incompatibility is fixed, I'm fine with the compiled help using the `classic` theme, but I'd like the online HTML Help to use `sphinx_rtd_theme`.

Can I get conditional compiling in `conf.py` based on the current builder?

```
if tags.has('builder_htmlhelp'):
    html_theme = 'classic'
else:
    html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
```

Doesn't work, because the `builder_xxx` [tag](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/configuration.html#conf-tags) does not get set until after `conf.py` is parsed.

---

### Update

The `make-doc.bat` batch script, above, does not actually exist in the real project.  I added it to create a minimum example to demonstrate the issue.  The actual build environment uses `setup.py` and

```
py -3.7 setup.py build_sphinx
```

to invoke Sphinx.  So a modification added to `setup.py` to add something to the build environment, which `conf.py` can detect and modify the theme based on, could work.

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

name = 'example'
version = '1.0'
release = '1.0.0'

setup(
    name=name,
    version=version,
    release=release,
    description='Help Example',
    python_requires='>=3',
    install_requires=['pywin32'],
    packages=['example'],
    command_options={
        'build_sphinx': {
            'project': ('setup.py', name),
            'version': ('setup.py', version),
            'release': ('setup.py', release),
            'source_dir': ('setup.py', 'source'),
            'builder': ('setup.py', 'html htmlhelp'),
            }
        },
    )
```

Comment: Did you try passing in configuration values into [`sphinx-build`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html#id2)? You could do so as environment variables, on the command line, or in your .bat file.

Comment: @StevePiercy I misrepresented the problem a bit.  There is no batch file to edit; `py -3.7 setup.py build_sphinx` is being used to invoke Sphinx.  The build environment is on a remote machine I don't have access to; I have to go through hoops to get a change made.  But I can easily change the `conf.py` file that Sphinx uses, so am really hoping for some way to detect the builder and switch themes inside of `conf.py`.  I do have control over the `setup.py` script as well, so if that can detect the builder and add arguments to the sphinx invocation, that might work too.

Comment: If memory serves me right, conf.py will have sys.args available for you to check what's in the invoking command line. That's where your formulation gets confusion, in your last comment you say the make file doesn't get invoked and you call sphinx-build (the command) directly using the setup.py `command-options`? Well, either hard code the builder you want in setup.py or cmd-line pass the builder into setup.py and have it parsed from sys.args into a `command_options` (that will afterwards be available when conf.py is called from setup.py)...I hope I was able to express myself.